# How to save more than two Strings in FileOutputStream and read those strings in different textviews?

Tags: java, android

I have three strings that I want to save in Internal storage of the Phone. But I am having problem while getting the output. Below is the program. I have just written down the important part only not other unimportant codes.

Out of those three strings string1 is passed in the `Spinner`(it is not shown here, because it is not a problem for me).

Now I want to load `string2` on the `textview1` and `string3` on the `textview2`.
The output I am getting is on `textview1` is both `string2` and `string3` and on `textview2` also I am getting both `string2` and `string3`.

Can somebody help me to get `string2` on `textview1` and `string3` on `textview2`.

PS: You see the spinner on the output, That is my output. I just kept there to make you understand that I have already string1 in spinner.

**Write.java**

```
    EditText filename, entry, pass;
String FILENAME, JOUR, PASSWORD;
    filename = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    entry = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    pass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO

 Auto-generated method stub
            FILENAME = filename.getText().toString();
            if (FILENAME.contentEquals("")){
                FILENAME = "passwordprotect";
            }
            JOUR = entry.getText().toString();
            PASSWORD = pass.getText().toString();

            try {
                FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                fos.write(JOUR.getBytes());
                fos.write(PASSWORD.getBytes());
                fos.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

**Read.java**

```
 TextView entry, passentry;
 entry = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
 passentry = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);

    private void openFile(String selectFile) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub


String value = "";

            FileInputStream fis;

            try {
                fis = openFileInput(selectFile);
                byte[] input = new byte[fis.available()];
                while(fis.read(input) != -1){
                    value += new String(input);

                }
                fis.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            entry.setText(value);
            passentry.setText(value);
        }
```

Output I am getting.

```
Spinner->string1
textview1->string2string3
textview2->string2string3
```

Comment: Wouldn't using Preferences be easier to store the strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Determine something to divide these two strings.

Depending on what sort of text you are storing in these textviews, different things may suffice. For example, you might be able to simply use a new line character to separate the two. Then you could just split your string `value` into two parts, storing each part in the respective text view.

Basically somehow divide the strings within the file, then split up your `value` string into two parts and store each part into the respective text view.

On another note, considering that you are just storing strings, have you considered using [Android Preferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref)?

Comment: Yes - the storage will need structure - simple delimiters as mentioned, something like JSON or XML, an sqlite database, there are many options to chose from either by suitability or simple developer familiarity/preference.

Comment: I want to save many strings in the internal storage, Not only one. The spinner acts like a heading of the textview1 and textview2. May be there are 10 files and when I choose one of the files from the spinner it will show strings on textview1 and textview2. It is possible on shared preferences?

Comment: You can store/retrieve a lot of strings in Shared Preferences, if that is what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

this is Write and Read

```
public static void read(Context context , String file , TextView tv ) {
    try {
        InputStream stream = context.openFileInput(file);
        if(stream != null ) {
            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(stream);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
            String receiveString = "";
            StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
            while ((receiveString = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                stringBuffer.append(receiveString);
            }
            tv.setText(stringBuffer);
            stream.close();
        }

    }catch (FileNotFoundException e){}
    catch (IOException e){}
}

public static void write(Context context , String file ,String str , EditText et) {
    str = et.getText().toString();

    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = context.openFileOutput(file, 0);
        fos.write(str.getBytes());
        fos.close();
    }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

now return this method on your class like that

```
write(this , FILENAME1 , JOUR, entry);
write(this , FILENAME2 , PASSWORD, pass);
read(this , FILENAME1 , entry);
read(this , FILENAME2 , passentry);
```